Google Maps Zoom Issue at Initialization in JavaScript
I've created this Google Map that has an issue at zoom level: when the first map appears (page loads) the zoom is in a Country level (expected: auto zoom to markers contents). But when I call initMap(); to redraw contents (without page reload) then expected boundaries occur (not Country zoom level anymore).
Google Maps is being called:
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxx&loading=async&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>

JS code:
let customerList = ....; //JSON object
let map = '';
let markers = [];

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: { lat: 35, lng: -105 },
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    $.each(customerList , function (a, customer) {        
        geocodeAddress(customer);
    });

    if (markers.length > 0) {
        let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

function geocodeAddress(customer) {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': customer.Address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {

            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: customer.Name,
                icon: markerIcon
            });

            let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: `<div><strong>${customer.Name}</strong><br>${customer.Address}</div>`
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            markers.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}


So, here is how I've solved this.
The issue occurs due to geocode being async, therefore initially markers.length is always zero: so markers.length > 0 is always false and map doesn't adjust itself initially. When it is called again, then markers.length > 0 is true and map adjustment occurs.
See below my updated code to consider this scenario.
Please note that customer.Adresss is a full address similar to "300 W 6th St, Austin, TX 78701, United States".
let customerList = ....; //JSON object
let map = '';

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: { lat: 35, lng: -105 },

        //Optional
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    });
    
    let markersList = [];
    let promises = [];

    $.each(customerList , function (a, customer) {
        promises.push(MarkersAux(customer, markersList));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        if (markersList.length > 0) {
            let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            $.each(markersList, function (a, marker) {
                bounds.extend(marker.position);
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error processing marker:', error);
    });
}

async function MarkersAux(customer, markersList) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': customer.Adresss }, (results, status) => {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: customer.Name,
                    icon: markerIcon, //Change to the desired icon
                });
                markersList.push(marker);
                resolve(marker);
            }
            else {
                console.error('Geocode was not successful for the following reason:', status);
                reject(status);
            }
        });
    });
}

